# Attaching file in email

Tags: android, email

I am sending email by attaching file with the email in the following code.
I am unable to get the right email in my inbox in the return

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
               intent.setType("image/jpeg");
               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddressList);  
               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject); 
               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText); 
               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText); 
               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.pic));
               Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "sPhotoUri=" + Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.pic));
               startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choice App to send email:"));
```

In the inbox the result is like that instead of an image.

```
���H��� !1AQaq�"�2��B#��Rb3�r��CS$�c����%!1AQq"2aB#��?�T@�� pJ�=>�
�
���` pH�`�A00V��7LM������H����]w�v��峆����щ�9N!�*y���k���_�{b�p[y8�~Leަݍ>�ˢm����#��1�һ.W�w�\��oj���7�8�#�s�V�U��j�Q���m�ִ0��~*S2�:V6��Oۋ&|Dj�h��+U�xy.�Q�Bʏ;
M   ʙ��b���Ɇ`v�v*�tgT��oX�Cf���)[��Io!F�v�޵��{cT269�ݮ�v6X8��������*S��@���A � H$s�@� �@� �-?b�� ��i@�P8iA H5�A H�
h3B���W���Km�:��EFcԗ��ߦ�x��ϣ��b,�$�H` �
j�x}�m<1��
u�Z;�,�������G�?��*Q췮%��޷�/SLϠu���x �c^�з#��?�lP�T�mK|������h�/�Lp4�T4;͝MWI\�a'���Zӥ��y�۝�7MV�FZ�E�#5��g��y�OL������.׉�Os3��h�n��d� �@���A � H$2A��I���M�I�th@�(j��>�H�A U���c��_A�����x-G��#asY�B��>�=I��n3��ù�9҉F,yq�A��x��/��c
��zڶ鄛��0`�~Q^�����s:"m-�8���8&���o����\XH�a9����-��n<��X�Y�}�YD�D���N�V��ne�Ѽ��5��;74�H�VRƫś�
����k@p���w%�~Z�O�9l�^[�����8w�ŏU{Ei���t�DP���y>G8.�<��m�VSP� v���C$���``��@� �B    Q��@� z ��$ P �5��
�i�A?�=�R\<˿�[�^n[,�Pz�H_j"դ���cZMr!y�H�s��}���ǲ[_߷ָlaϋ�H��{�Y�S�o�4;�-��haqk^d��:F,��[�3��{t^��j�X��n&�n��<��9�s_��k;LV�,�������d���D��L�]p���s��T��+�e�=�6� �m.?(
#Igh�YZ���A����W8<�c�"��]$f�m��m��y��H=٭�+X�ȑ΍��Q��|����X����v��6�
:�����~��O���h
�HD�� �@�@� �s� �$�@��TA 0A&���=*@� �J  ��H4�p;�e�]��;h�3��iq��5�=����Π���]r�]�\�\+�/�����y����絊[s`m(�ff\f�\+�z��&p5�*�0������!r�Y^��m<��:On�f�4׿�����H]�X���n�}�-��2i�����;l-�y�4�R�q=��>��0u�&k��� U��^j��&̦��Q�{;e�/���>�e}g�?-��A�w�Z�6^����\�^�ܖ�����[�-\*�њ��onR0=1���ܽ�gl�[�;�w���j�Q��ښX��]���].�ǥ%y�G?*�;���0�p�A�H$��A HI��BA* p* �$  ��@� �$��pgMo&�����Vw��ӌ�s�`�?|�ݳ�m_{p-�t�%�PjI"�.k�����nv���ŀ���㻱����70�p ���p�yiV����~bGeW�����;��Ѵ7�r���mY�(�,�9�B^N��$Q��*Us��}Ǩ��\�.q36"<´ǳO��ٜ:��!�ѱ�T��X��1�S���:i��N�����K?���S7p�Ml��};0�I�ߧ?g��+��r��b9���?N{�-;)����>w�K�l���|�R$$L H����s���    �H�@�b�a�A* z pH�@ pJ�$oT���9W��7�,����O�úg�o��d�����Kv��N1�8s^g[����{ ����h�k*94��\V�^g��)w����nG;��h(���./����m�z����nd��դ{�Z;���\^��#do�E<ˮ�F����Q����y!���R㨑S�
�^z[O��k<�;x#�����T�'�}���v��sV��' t�����A��     ���A0L �A 8$��@�A Q��:�e����K�9�`�gF�}�m<5��k��:�ƿj����o.c��5�
x/
����:��Po��M�߶��HY_[lp�|℁�c�F�җ�^ٹ�q,>f��-s{9k8yw�d���i�aZØBd ���k67*��R}��̚�na�ņF�n`�J��k[�T1]�8�d��IF�\3�WI�u��2��,"����u��g����侞��a��7"�����8A ��I�  �   �B����  �   �&*�mA H({PHD�����5ι�4y�@�T��R�=�T�YY�Vɢ!�
l���xz�����>hΖD����9�s�[��E�m��G��  dn9�!#��\ӊ�S���nYQB|��
U�眵�hxp9��ܡ�5I%Z<�:�ZV�,o՘ڢ�y$�y`f�������y>�O�.*���@��   t t$?A x �$3A. �&  ��` �A �`�rD67��~$�e88�����N�j�
�d��2n����Iu��Q�pTiۗ���?��w#k��0�0������ԭ��b퇡���m�q���W�!��x�Uࡌ���VH�M���DM2�!.{��*\]��R�=<���$vM��y���[�0<�d6�|WM$�P�H��I�4�7}����F�3�Z������l��V4>��$�%L�m��n����q�Q�r�-
h�b�}�RȾ��d.=��>���������×w���=H p��8@�8@���*�� � �A6��� �&�P)f������f�Y�1���Hh�1��U�q^��QXApa魏�!f���0\0���i����~��͹�0��P�>���]�+��I�o�yy�k�I�kZ;�+�x�ٜRN���C�����c~���p�Ճ��d�0ET'49���q%Ē~*d;p��}ȣv�}I�p�o�=���̑����ƺ�*/
�_KY�z�|��\ӭ���>�n����޷��hd���2���ur|[�Ot�w���3����j���9��Ci�b߻�0dDMk0��f��L�#�6u�3�{, ۫��W��?�|��� ���v��p��@�@����|
    �m(,��A I���    7$�F�:�\�bjJ0��M�?b�fs:kn��������f�J4-���B�b��
��t��
-���,�tT+8�8�S#�ۗ   yv�j�;
����=ؒ���aE����8y���n.�P�asw�����'�ykB�b����
o��i�NV2N|�n�s�BEZ�U����y�ᱚ��ܹm�.���w:;c�]��o�͹�N�m�$3>�zC(��sEX�
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out -

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"email"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Test");
//has to be an ArrayList
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
//convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
for (String file : filePaths)
{
    File fileIn = new File(file);
    Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
    uris.add(u);
}
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
context.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

And, also just refer previous question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570914/android-how-do-i-attach-a-temporary-generated-image-to-an-email) about attach the images in Email through Intent.

Comment: filePaths is an array of paths or a single string

Comment: I just done that with [this](http://www.ziddu.com/download/18600975/AudioCaptureDemo.zip.html) example. Just refer it out. And, post me if you've any doubts.

Comment: What about the previous question.

Answer (score 4):

this works

```
 File imgFile = new File(picturePath);

                 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:???@gmail.com"));    
                         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");  
                         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");
                         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
                         startActivity(emailIntent);
```

picturePath coud be "/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/yourpic.jpg"