# Attachment Issue in Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

I've been working on Android program to send email with an attachment (text/plain)using `Intent` with `Intent.ACTION_SEND` I used `Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)` However, when I tried to have multiple files attached to the same mail by calling `Intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)` multiple times, it failed to work. None of the attachment show up in the email.Thanks in Advance

```
      final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      System.out.println(emailText+emailTo);
      emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,emailText);
      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{emailTo});

      //has to be an ArrayList
      ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

      //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
      try
      {
            for (String file : filePaths)
            {
                File fileIn = new File(context.getFilesDir(),file);
                System.out.println(fileIn+"yes");
                Uri u =  Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                uris.add(u);
                System.out.println(u);
            }
      emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uris);
      context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
      }
```

Comment: Try my old [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9273051/940096) to this question.

Comment: Your answer is same as my Question

Comment: Are you trying to attach multiple files there?

Comment: yes as i mentioned above in my question.

Comment: When i am using this code the attachment are shown but after sending the mail i dont receive any attachment.

Comment: Weird thing.. Try my code once in that answer..

Comment: Yes i did,but had a same problem...not receive any attachment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ACTION_SEND_MUTIPLE instead of ACTION_SEND

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: thanks, I did it but got the same problem,i wasted my 2 days on a single issue.please help if u can

Comment: Which email app do you use? I get a error when using the standard "Email" app "file too large to attach". But I don't get the warning when using Gmail. Try using another mail app and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I was use both Gmail as well as yahoo too,but i didn't receive any attachment in both app,i dont know where i m doing wrong.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you run it in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

**Ensure that the second argument *file* supplies only a valid file name. your problem might be there...**

```
File fileIn = new File(context.getFilesDir(),file);
```

The Following code works without any issue..

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
//...
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
uris.add(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/HOME/Pictures/1.png"));
uris.add(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/HOME/Pictures/2.png"));
uris.add(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/HOME/Pictures/3.png"));
uris.add(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/HOME/Pictures/4.png"));
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivity(emailIntent);
```