# How to attach Audio file to E-Mail using Intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to attach an audio file to an email.

I am attaching it but cannot get that attachment on the receiver side. I don't know exactly which mimetype i have to use for this file.

I already tried `setType("*/*")`. But It still doesn't work for me. Is it even possible, and if so, then how can I?

I already found a lot here on SO as well as on Google, but still haven't gotten the right solution.

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {});
email.setType("image/jpeg");
email.setType("audio/mpeg3");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, TAG);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getText(R.string.Message));

Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/Male_Hard_2.mp3");

email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Comment: post your code what u have tried?

Comment: you have tried `email.setType("audio/mp3");` and also check uri of file is right

Comment: yes i tried email.setType("audio/mp3") but still got the same problem.i attached that audio file successfully on sender side but cannot get that file on Receiver file.

Answer (score 1):

the following link is helpful for me [Attaching file in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272964/attaching-file-in-email).. the key part is

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    for (String file : filePaths)
    {
        File fileIn = new File(file);
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
        uris.add(u);
    }
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris); // intent is your email intent
```

Comment: but what mime type i have to apply for an audio file attachment?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE)
    .setType("audio/wav").setType("image/jpeg")
    .setType("message/rfc822")
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails)
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strDetails)
    .putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris)
    .putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, strAudioFilePath), "Send your email in:"));
```

In the above code, **strAudioFilePath** is the path of the Audio file.

Comment: still i am getting same problem.is there any permission i have to give to attach audio file?

Comment: Add these permissions into Manifest and try it again <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: but i dont want to record audio.Still i have to give that permission?