# Sending an html file as attachment

Tags: android, android-intent

What is the type i can use for intent for sending an email with an html page attachment? Whatever type i use, the sent mail contains an empty page as an attachment

Here's some code

```
String root = "/data/data/com.email/files/";
                String fileName = "Payslip.html";
                if (true) {
                    attachment = new File(root, fileName);
                }

                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(

                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,

                new String[] { address.getText().toString() });

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,

                subject.getText());

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,

                emailtext.getText());

                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        Uri.fromFile(attachment));

                EmailActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(
                        emailIntent,

                        "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: instead of emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream"); try emailIntent.setType("file/html");

Comment: [Try to see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3586478/940096)

Comment: It seems that your code is right. I'am using the same for sending a generated PDF file. Are you sure that the file Payslip.html is not empty? Just create a simple webview and view this file in the app.

Comment: @Dya: I tried ur suggestion, But still no change :(

Comment: @lischc:I pulled the file out through file explorer, its a 12 kb file and has contents too. Were u able to send ur PDF?

Comment: have u added proper permissions in ur manifest?

Comment: Ya, i've given WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to it;

Comment: @Spk: Thnx for the ref; but is there no way atleast to read internal files??

Comment: @MoJo yes I was able to send my PDF. Have you tried context.getFilesDir() to retrieve a File object to the "files" directory. With that you can also get another File object to your stored HTML page. You can also use the File.exists() and File.isFile() method for checking.

Comment: Thnx for all the help guys, atlast i stored it in sdcard then emailed it, no permission probs or empty attachments:) happy for now:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now, we can use context.getFilesDir() to retrieve a File object to the "files" directory. With that you can also get another File object to your stored HTML page. You can also use the File.exists() and File.isFile() method for checking. Thanks for [Christian Lisching](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526369/christian-lischnig)