# how to get selected image from gallery in android?

Tags: android

I have a problem: I have a function that brings me the image from the gallery ;but when I select the image, I don't get it.

```
public void funzione(View v){
int SELECT_IMAGE=1;
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);
```

I have to email this image, but I don't now how to implement this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setType("application/octet-stream"); 
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ "prova@libero.it" });
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test subj");
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "corpo mail test");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email"));

}
```

Comment: Please refer to the highest-voted [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android)

Answer (score 12):

Declare Global Variables just after your class declaration at the top:

```
 private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
 private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;
 Bitmap thumbnail = null;
```

Call the intent like this: (Your funizone() function)

```
   public void funzione(){
       Intent in = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                      startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

   }
```

Handle the result like this: Declare this outside of your onCreate anywhere in the class.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);     

     if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){

         Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

thumbnail is your picture, now play with it!

Comment: sorry but...where i have to insert this code??i have to change my code with this or i have to insert your code?

Comment: Insert the above code, in your funzione method.
Refer here as how to send this image as an attachment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570914/android-how-do-i-attach-a-temporary-generated-image-to-an-email

Comment: Thanks for the code.  Why did google make getting an image from photo gallery so complicated.  Why does it take 6-7 lines of code to create the Bitmap?

Comment: In a mobile environment, resources are few management of memory is a tough job for the processor hence these extra lines of code for optimization.

Comment: @Nun'e chai how to find name of selected image

Comment: Concentrate on the lines: `Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();` from here you can do the following: 
     `String s = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);` 


Here is the function: 


`public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}`

Comment: Although managedQuery() is deprecated, you can find an alternative [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath/9989900#9989900)

Answer (score 3):

```
package com.example.assignment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: please post an explaination too not just an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Put This in Action Listener from where to choose image **

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

This second Action Listener

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 200);
```

After Return from a gallery, Result get Through request code **here code is 100 and 200 for both **

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri imageUri=data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                reg_certificate.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        if(requestCode == 200 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null){
            Uri imageUri=data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
                org_logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -6):

**Use Following Code for add image in apps.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.test2);
        }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    /* Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.*/
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

Comment: First you store your image inside the res->drawable-mdpi folder in your project.

Comment: That's not at all what he was trying to do