# please tell me,how to open gallery images into image view in new activity android

Tags: android, xml

How do I open gallery images into image view in new activity android.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `onActivityResult`

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14978710/2065418 and set the `Bitmap` to your `ImageView` with `yourImageView.setImageBitmap(yourBitmap);`